# how to set the hidden and shown column after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

hello i need a help in setting a cookie in javascript because it is the first time i make a cookie and i can not load the cookie in the browser. here is my html and jquery code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th><b class='show' style='cursor:pointer;font-weight: unset;'>Datum</b><b class='hide' style='display:none;cursor:pointer;font-weight: unset;'>Datum</b></th>
    <th><b class='show1' style='cursor:pointer;font-weight: unset;'>Zeitfenster</b><b class='hide1' style='display:none;cursor:pointer;font-weight: unset;'>Zeitfenster</b></th>
    <th class='orgaunit' style='display:none;'>Betriebstelle</th>
    <th class='orgaitem' style='display:none;'>Betriebselemente</th>
    <th>Zeit (von - bis)</th>
    <th>Pause (von - bis)</th>
    <th>Stunden</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Bemerkung</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td> hello</td> 
    <td style='text-align:left;padding-left:4%;' >hello2</td>
    <td class='orgaunit' style= 'display:none;'>hello3 </td>
    <td class='orgaitem' style= 'display:none;'>hello4 </td>
    <td> hello 5</td>
    <td>"hello 6</td>
    <td  style="padding-right:15px;" >hello 7</td>
    <td>hello 8</td>
    <td>hello 9</td>
    </tr></table>
<script src="2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" +     exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
 }

function getCookie(c_name) {
var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
        return unescape(y);
    }
  }
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var theColumn = $(".show").click(function(){
 $(".hide").css({display:"inline-block"});
 $(".show").css({display:"none"});
 $(".orgaunit").css({display:"table-cell"});
 setCookie("selectedColumn", theColumn, 1);

  });
  //setCookie("selectedColumn", theColumn, 3);
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".show").click(function(){
     getCookie("selectedColumn");
   });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
 var theColumn2 =  $(".hide").click(function(){
 $(".show").css({display:"inline-block"});
 $(".hide").css({display:"none"});
 $(".orgaunit").css({display:"none"});
 });
  setCookie("selectedColumn2", theColumn2, 3);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  var theColumn3 =  $(".MainContent").ready(function(){
  $(".show").css({display:"inline-block"});
  $(".hide").css({display:"none"});
  $(".orgaunit").css({display:"none"});
  });
  setCookie("selectedColumn3", theColumn3, 3);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".hide").value = getCookie("selectedColumn");
});

$(".show1").click(function(){
   $(".hide1").css({display:"inline-block"});
   $(".show1").css({display:"none"});
   $(".orgaitem").css({display:"table-cell"});
});

$(".hide1").click(function(){
   $(".show1").css({display:"inline-block"});
   $(".hide1").css({display:"none"});
   $(".orgaitem").css({display:"none"});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have made a shown column and hide it again it is the column `Betriebstelle` and the column `Betriebellement` and after i refresh the page it is hidden again i need to save the condition of saving these columns if it is shown or hidden that after refreshing the page it is the same as i chosed

the cookies i did are setted in the browser but i can not get it back aagin
please help me

Comment: no php code here

Comment: i took away the php code cause i do not need it it is only concern the javascript cookie and making the browser remember the case of hiding or showing the column

Comment: then remove the php tag from the question. It will mislead other professionals

Comment: okay i will sorry :(

Comment: can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Why are you want to use a cookie? I would do it with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), if you won't need a cookie on server side.

Comment: i set the localStorage and the cookie very well but then when i refresh the broweser forget them completely

Comment: would you help me please and make it on this code in a fiddle if you do not mind please

Comment: would you help me  `@Brissy`